# How to query NEAR node block height by near-cli?

Tags: near

How to query NEAR node block height by near-cli?
I didn't find it on https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-cli

Answer (score 0):

You can use `near repl` which launches interactive Node.js shell with NEAR connection available to use. The repl's initial context contains `nearAPI`, `near` and `account` (source: `near-cli --help`)

shell:

```
$> near repl
> let response = await near.connection.provider.block({finality: "final"})
> response
```

the response will give you a bunch of info, height among other things. Or you can go with

```
> response.header.height
```

and you'll get only the value of the `height` field